# Creating a searchable collection of rooms

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to learn C++ again, trying to do all the "modern" stuff (e.g., avoid pointers in favor of references) and I found that I have some trouble understanding how references and lifetimes work. I'm using clang with `-std=c++11`.

I want to have a RAII-class, `RoomList` that basically wraps a `map<int, Room>`. On construction of `RoomList`, it will create all the Rooms (imagine loading them from a data file or so) and the map, and on destruction it should free the map and all Rooms.

This code works, but I don't fully understand all of it (I've done a lot of "randomly trying stuff" to get it to work). ([GIST is here](https://gist.github.com/mstum/5c0993de3f6af62050a8))

The `Room` class:

```
class Room {
public:
  explicit Room(int id, const std::string& name) : m_id(id), m_name(name) {}
  const std::string& GetName() const { return m_name; }
  const int& GetEnterCount() const { return m_enterCount; };
  void OnEnter() { ++m_enterCount; }
private:
  std::string m_name; // should this be const?
  int m_id; // should this be const?
  int m_enterCount = 0;
};
```

The `RoomList` class:

```
class RoomList {
public:
  RoomList();
  ~RoomList() = default; // Is this needed? Rule of three?
  RoomList(const RoomList&) = delete; // Don't want copies
  RoomList& operator=(RoomList const&) = delete;
  const Room& GetRoom(int index);
private:
  // Should this be <int, Room> or <int, Room&>?
  std::map<int, Room> m_rooms;
};

RoomList::RoomList() {
  // Read all the rooms, e.g., from a data file
  // What is the lifetime of the Room I'm creating?
  // Room doesn't have copy or move ctors
  // Also, I'm not initializing m_rooms - what is its lifetime?
  m_rooms.emplace(0, Room(0, "Start Room"));
}

// Returning a reference to const Room - no one should be able to modify Room, except by calling room.OnEnter()
// room.OnEnter() should modify the Room inside the map (Individual Rooms are basically Singletons)
const Room& RoomList::GetRoom(int index) {
  auto result = m_rooms.find(index);
  if(result != m_rooms.end())
  {
    // result is a local var - is result->second valid after return?
    return result->second;
  }

  // Considering Optional<Room>
  // https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/
  throw "Invalid Index";
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
int main() {
  RoomList rooms;
  auto room = rooms.GetRoom(0);
  std::cout << "Name: " << room.GetName() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I left some comments, but basically the things I'm confused about:

- I'm not initializing the `m_rooms` map - will it be default initialized to live as long as the `rooms` variable in main.cpp is in scope?
- I have a map of `Room`s, but I want to return `Room` references. Will returning a `Room` have any negative side effects? (e.g., is there some automatic creation of a wrapper object or even a copy of `Room` going on?)
- Is `result->second` even still valid after a return? `result` is a local variable that should die when the function ends, but I'm returning what second points to, so that should be good?
- Would I need to implement `~RoomList` to make sure all the Rooms are freed? Or does `std::map::emplace` own the constructed Room?
- If I wanted to return something by value, how would I need to allocate it? For example, imagine I've added this to `Room`, wouldn't I return a stack-allocated variable?

This code works, but I think it shouldn't:

```
class Room {
public:
  // ...
  std::string GetRoomDescription();
}

std::string Room::GetRoomDescription()
{
  // What's the lifetime of "result"?
  // In C, this would be stack-allocated and dead
  // when the function returns.
  std::stringstream result;
  result << "ID: " << m_id << " - Name: " << m_name;
  return result.str();
}

// main.cpp
std::cout << "Room: " << room.GetRoomDescription() << std::endl;
```

Comment: There is a difference between your main here, and the main in your gist, that actually makes quite a difference.

Comment: @Zulan Indeed, it misses the const-ness issue of GetRoom. I've just experimented with some of the recommendations in your answer and ran into that. I didn't consider const-ness important (i was more worried about lifetime) but now that this stuff makes more sense I see the issue. The class design needs major tweaking to separate concerns, after I've figured out how C++ ownership/lifetime works.

Comment: What's RAII about this code? There's no resource being acquired.

Comment: @Barry Not sure if I'm using the term correctly, but the intent is that `RoomList` owns all the `Room`s, and that the Rooms are alive as long as `RoomList` is alive.

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues here:

```
  auto room = rooms.GetRoom(0);
```

Here you do copy the `Room` because `auto` does not imitate the 'reference part'. To bind a reference to the internal map entry, you need to both return by reference and assign to a reference type. Based on your gist, I assume you would think that if you then call `room.OnEnter`, the Room is also updated in the `RoomList`. This is not the case, because it is a copy. Therefore you would want to use:

```
  auto& room = rooms.GetRoom(0);
```

instead. But for that to work, `RoomList::GetRoom` should return a non-const reference, so that you can actually modify it. In turn there should also be a const `RoomList::GetRoom` that also returns a const reference.

However, there should also be a non-const `RoomList::GetRoom` that returns a non-const reference, so that you can actually call non-const methods on the returned rooms.

To avoid running into that issue - you might want to delete the copy constructors and assignment operators of `Room`. If you further wanted to enforce that all Room objects are owned only by `RoomList` you could even make the `Room` constructor private and friend `RoomList`.

> I'm not initializing the m_rooms map - will it be default initialized to live as long as the rooms variable in `main.cpp` is in scope?

Yes

> I have a map of Rooms, but I want to return Room references. Will returning a Room have any negative side effects? (e.g., is there some automatic creation of a wrapper object or even a copy of Room going on?)

Not for `std::map`. You can delete the copy constructor and assignment operator or `Room`, that will ensure you make no copies somewhere else in the code also.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6442829/620382 for a listing of iterator/reference invalidations in standard containers.

> Is `result->second` even still valid after a return? result is a local variable that should die when the function ends, but I'm returning what second points to, so that should be good?

Yes. `result` points to the internal `value_type` of the map.

> Would I need to implement ~RoomList to make sure all the Rooms are freed? Or does std::map::emplace own the constructed Room?

`RoomList::m_rooms` own the constructed `Room`s. More technically speaking:

m_rooms.emplace(0, Room(0, "Start Room"));

Here a temporary `Room` object is created, which is then moved into the `std::pair<int, Room>` that is construed inside of the map. In C++14 you can use `std::piecewise_construct` to even skip the temporary `Room` object. But as long as you have a move constructor, which you have by default, you are fine.

> If I wanted to return something by value, how would I need to allocate it? For example, imagine I've added this to Room, wouldn't I return a stack-allocated variable?

If you do not declare the return value to be a reference (which you do not in your example), then it is returned by copy. But the C++ rules and compilers are good so that you will either get a move (cheaper than actual copy) or even omitting it alltogether when possible.

> // Considering Optional

If you document it properly, it would be actually fine to return a raw pointer here, with `nullptr` meaning that it is not available. The raw pointer (similar to the raw reference) does not imply ownership. You just need to make sure the caller does never reference it without checking. `optional` (also available in boost and soon in the standard).

The funny thing about your code is, that you have *randomly* written proper and safe code. IMHO this is a nice property especially about modern C++. There is actually no explicit resource allocation (like `new`) in your code - when you allocate resources implicitly, through member variables, C++ will behave nicely by default and also implicitly release the resources.

```
  std::string m_name; // should this be const?
  int m_id; // should this be const?
```

Yes, it would be a good idea to make those `const`.

```
const int& GetEnterCount() const { return m_enterCount; };
```

I would consider it a uncommon to return an `int` by const reference here (as opposed to a simple copy). I don't have a strong argument for or against, but lets just take note that `std::vector::size` doesn't return an `const int&` either.

```
  RoomList& operator=(RoomList const&) = delete;
```

You should put the `const` before `RoomList` for consistency.
You also might want to explicitly `default` or `delete` the move constructor and assignment operators. I would say neither would hurt.

In `Room`, you list `m_id` and `m_name` in a different order in the initializer list. This can lead to confusion because the initialization order follows the order from member declaration (`m_name` then `m_id`). Therefore this is a compiler warning.

So the tip is, compile with maximal warnings, e.g. `-Wall -pedantic` for gcc. Also it can be helpful to run your code with `valgrind` to check for any leaks.

Answer (score 3):

`explicit` only makes sense on single-argument-constructors and on conversion operators, but `Room::Room(int id, const std::string& name)` has two arguments...

`Room` has 4 implicitly defined special-member-functions: Copy- and Move- Ctor and assignment.
Luckily, as all members representing additional resources (the `std::string`) use RAII, they do *the right thing*.
At least if copying a room makes any kind of sense, which I doubt.

If you make a member `const`, all but the copy-constructor would be deleted...

---

Why don't you allow moving a `RoomList`? As an aside, explicitly defaulting the move-constructor and/or move-assignment-operator in the class will disable implicit generation of copy-ctor and copy-assignment-operator.

There is only one reason to explicitly default a destructor in-class: To mark it `virtual`.
As an aside, if a special-member-function is user-declared but not defaulted in-class, or any of the base-classes versions aren't trivial, it cannot be trivial.

If you upgrade to C++14, your list of rooms should not be a `std::map` but a `std::set`, and `Room` should be comparable according to the room-number, and comparable with numbers.

There's a better way to put `Room`s in your list:

```
m_rooms.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(0),
    std::forward_as_tuple(0, "Start Room"));
```

In C++17, there will be [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)...

You were right that you must not return a local variable. But that's not what you are doing anyway, you are returning a reference to the object the local variable (an iterator) points to, which is harmless.

Be aware that `return 0;` is implicit in `main`.

Your last snippet is ok, the temporary created by `result.get()` gets moved (though RVO applies, so it actually gets substituted) to the functions return-value.